# Varieties of abstention in review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When I look through the review queues there are often many which I skip for various reasons. These include:

- not having a clue whether the answer is good or not, the matter being beyond my ken,
- a general world-weariness at the issues raised,
- having no strong opinion one way or the other,
- thinking it certainly problematic, but being paralysed with indecision over which crime has been committed (most often overawed by the magnitude of the inanity),
- not being sure whether the merits of the case weigh one way or another, but being able to articulate cases in both directions.

Of course, this rather over-emphasises my equivocation: at other times I'm like Dredd on Speed.

My question concerns my general dissatisfaction with all these kinds of abstention being "Skip"s. Are there negative implications for me or for the site skipping in these various circumstances? Is skipping as if I'd never seen it (which I have been assuming) or does it have other implications for the question, site, or me? Is skipping actually the right thing to do in these various circumstances?

Is profligate skipping dissolute?

Comment: Good question! I've often wondered, but was diffident about asking in case the response was *"Oh! **You're** the one who keeps skipping so much!"*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Skipping is definitely not dissolute.

You have at least considered the post and consciously decided that you cannot honestly pass an opinion.  This has to be better for the site than clicking either the exterminate or the keep button without proper consideration.

Comment: +1 Quite right! As a syntax/grammar person, I'm acutely aware of people close-voting grammar questions because they don't appreciate the issue in hand, or don't find it interesting. In particular, I find people who are rampant SWR -ers  close-vote questions because they intuitively know *how* to say something when the question asks *why* we say something the way we do. When we can't be bothered to read or think about a question carefully we *should* abstain so that useful and interesting questions can be asked and answered without our dumb interfering. We can't each do this for all questions!